# python: how to include 0 in boolean logic

Tags: python, boolean-logic

I have a variable `var` that can have either an integer value or `None`.
I am trying to display its value. If the value is an integer value then I would print the integer value, but if it is `None`, I would like to display nothing `""`.

The following code works well for all integer values besides 0.

```
var = 0
print var or ""
```

The following code displays `""`. 
I would like to display 0 here instead of `""`. Any workarounds?

Comment: `var if var is not None else ""`

Comment: `print("" if var is None else var)` this could work but it's not a boolean logic.

Comment: Or `var if var or var == 0 else ''`.

Comment: All of the above options work. That was more simple than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

0 of any numeric type is false (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing so you can't have it as true using boolean logic. As noted in the comments you can use an expression instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var = 0
print var or ("" and var)
```